# MySql slow_log query grouping

Tags: mysql, performance, count, grouping

I'm trying to collect some stats on the worst performing queries on my database.
I've switched on MySQL's slow query logging and have been monitoring the slow_log table in the database.

I'm trying to get a count of unique query count per day, something like this:

```
Date              count      query
2016-11-20        15         'SELECT * FROM XYAA'
2016-11-20        196        'SELECT count(*) FROM BLAH'
2016-11-19        7          'SELECT * FROM XYAA'
2016-11-19        296        'SELECT count(*) FROM BLAH'
```

slow_log table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log' |
```

Comment: Give us the structures, do you expect us to guess them ?

Comment: @fancyPants, how is running a count query re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @sagi I've added the slow_query table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(start_time) as `date`,
       COUNT(*) as `count`,
       sql_text as query
FROM `slow_log`
GROUP BY DATE(start_time) , sql_text
```

Comment: Better than `COUNT(*)` is `SUM(query_time)`.  The latter measures the query's impact on the system -- Whether it is lots of short queries or a few long queries.